# Proof that $\left \langle 0\mid \hat{S}\mid 0 \right \rangle = e^{\sum (\text{all connected vacuum diagrams})}$

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

In my book on QFT  (Lancaster & Blundell) they state the following equation, without proof: $$\left \langle 0\mid \hat{S}\mid 0 \right \rangle  = e^{\sum (\text{all connected vacuum  diagrams})}$$ where $\hat{S}$ is the S-matrix. This is what I tried:
If we expand the expression above in terms using dyson's series, we get:$$\left \langle 0\mid \hat{S}\mid 0 \right \rangle = \left \langle 0\mid Te^{-i\int d^{4}z\hat{H}_{I}(z)}\mid0  \right \rangle$$ and then maclaurin expanding the exponential gives us the following:$$\left \langle 0\left | T \left [ 1-i\int d^{4}z\hat{H}_I(z)+\frac{(-i)^{2}}{2}\int d^{4}yd^{4}w\hat{H}_I(y)\hat{H}_I(w)+... \right ]\right | 0\right \rangle$$    I am not sure where to go from here, however. Can anyone help me complete this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that each term in your MacLaurin$^\dagger$ series represents one or more diagrams. Since they are sandwiched between the vacuum $|0>$, the only nonzero diagrams are those with no external lines. In particular, there will be 'disconnected' diagrams where not all vertices are connected. If you agree that the series generates *all* the diagrams, then the [linked cluster theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram#Connected_diagrams:_linked-cluster_theorem) tells you that the exponential of those are the connected ones (where connected means that all vertices in the diagram are connected).

$\dagger$ Most people would call it a Dyson series.

If this is more appropriate as a comment, feel free to move/remove it. I haven't posted enough to comment yet.